# c++ - resolve all symbolic links defined in a file path

Tags: c++, symlink, filepath

### Short version

how do I get a resolved path from a path that one of its dirs are symbolic link:

example:

Say path = /x/y/d/f1 where y is a symbolic link to /a/b

so the result of resolved file path would be:
/x/a/b/d/f1

### Long version

I'd like to write a c++ function that copy files from dir1 to dir2 (of course this is not the actual issue but a reduction of bigger and more complex problem).

Prior to the copy process I'd like to remove all files in dir2 that are going to be copied from dir1.
Say I have:

- Dir1 = /a/b/c/d
- Dir2 = /x/y/d/

Assume I have file 'f1' in dir1 and file 'f1' in dir2, so my process would do:

1. remove /x/y/d/f1
2. copy /a/b/c/d/f1 to /x/y/d/f1

My problem is the following:

Say dir 'y' is a symbolic link to /a/b/c/. 
Now when I remove /x/y/d/f1, I am actually removing /a/b/c/d/f1.
(my example may have holes in it, but I hopw you get the idea)

I'd like to avoid this, meaning, when I come to remove /x/y/d/f1 I want to be able to know that I'll be removing /x/y/d/f1 and skip that remove

I tried using POSIX readlink() function but it only works when the file 'f1' itself is a symbolic link BUT does not work when one of its parent dirs is a symbolic link.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Following link will give you the answer.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1126617

You can use following code to resolve symilnks:

```
char buf[512];
int count = readlink("/x/y/d", buf, sizeof(buf));
if (count >= 0) {
    buf[count] = '\0';
    printf("%s -> %s\n", argv[1], buf);
}
```

In above code "d" path component should be the symlink. So you will have to iterate and resolve each path component.

Comment: You should use `memset(buf,0,sizeof(buf))` and `readlink("/x/y/d",buf,sizeof(buf) - 1)` since readlink does not append null-termination to the string.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the said collision scenario, it is easier to create a canary file and try to access it through the other constructed path. If you meant the question in general, for full-dir operations.

If it's not clear: if you create /x/y/d/TEMP123456 it will appear as /a/b/c/d/TEMP123456 (or the other way around) if they actually point to same dirs.

For a single file it may be even easier: open the source file for exclusive access before trying to delete it in target dir. (I'm not sure how reliable that is if you add NFS systems to the mix.)

Comment: Not trying to avoid collision. as I said, my problem is bigger than that, However I'd like to better understand your suggestion. can you elaborate on that? what do you mean "access it through"